# RedirectToRoute twice in one return (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I need a view `shipping address` and `Show Total` at one time on my checkout nopCommerce page.

Now I have `shipping address` and after "on click" "Show Total" shows.

`shipping address` and  `Show Total` are showed by some actions, which return `RedirectToRoute`.

I want to know next: how i can use `RedirectToRoute` twice in one `return` in action?

Or maybe there are another way to return two methods which return JSON?

Comment: *how i can RedirectToRoute twice in one "return" in action* What do you want?, modify your question and add whole scenario

Comment: I need view "shipping address" and "Show Total" at one time on one page. Now i have "shipping address" and after "on click" "Show Total"  shows

Comment: OK, it's seems like one page check out, in that case you can use an ajax. on click you have to perform two operation, first which regularly call and get shipping address and second is ajax call which gives you order total

Comment: i saw in your profile that you work with nopCommerce. I need to do this in nopCommerce. Can you give me some details how i can do this there?

Comment: Ohh..sure :) which version are you using of nopCommerce?

Comment: probably the newest

Comment: OK, Let me check. Before that i advice you to modified your question, and make it more clear other wise you will get down-vote here. and please refer [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using one page checkout or multi page checkout?

Comment: I use one page checkout

Comment: OK, there is a method in the `CheckoutController` called `OpcSaveBilling` which hit when you click on `continue` of `BillingAddress`. you have to add total with return. you can add total using `decimal? shoppingCartTotalBase = _orderTotalCalculationService.GetShoppingCartTotal(cart, ignoreRewardPoints);` which gives you the total or you can take a reference from multiple checkout which already display total with checkout attribute.

Comment: it isn't resolved because i need show "ShoppingCartTotal" before clicking on "continue" of "BillingAddress" :(

Comment: *before clicking on "continue" of "BillingAddress"* But you want to show it on shipping address tab

Comment: I want to have only "billing address" "payment method" and "total" tabs. Firstly there must be displayed "billing address" and "total", after click there must be "payment method" and "total" and finally click is on "confirm".In the start i didn`t say that in my program shipping and billing tabs are one. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. Now i have next: "total" opens when i click "continue" on "payment method" tab. I made it with next code in _public.accordion.js_ (openSection method) :
`if (section.attr('id') != this.currentSectionId ) {
            if (this.currentSectionId != 'opc-confirm_order')
            {
                this.closeExistingSection();
            }
...
}`

Comment: Also i try to set up "total" tab from start with modifying script on bottom of `OnePageCheckout.cshtml` :
`Accordion.init('checkout-steps', '.step-title', true);
        Accordion.openSection('#opc-confirm_order');
        Accordion.openSection('#opc-billing');` 
But it doesn't work